# How to fix network error in Axios React native?

Tags: react-native

I have used Axios for API call in react native but get result Network Error.

```js
const config = {
                method: 'post',
                url: BASE_URL+"/auth/login",
                headers: {        
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                data: {
                        username: "physician@doral.com",
                        password: "password",
                        device_token: "",
                        device_type: 1,
                        latitude: "",
                        longitude: ""
                      }
              };
        
             axios(config)    
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
          
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log("err :", err); 
                Alert.alert("something went to wrong.",err.message);    
              });
```

I had use above axios function but get network error in react native. how to fix network error in react native Application.

Comment: Hey Suraj, Can you provide the network error you are receiving. I don't see anything wrong code wise.

Comment: [AxiosError: Network Error] and error status : undefined show me.

Comment: What is the full error. Can you provide `err` from the catch block.

Comment: LOG  err : [AxiosError: Network Error]
 LOG  err status : undefined

i have only this type of log in metro

Comment: That is not enough information to help you. I am not sure what metro is. Need the output from the catch block.

Comment: can you tell me how to get full information?